# Google Cloud Platform: online prediction timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timeout, httprequest

I deployed my model on GCP AI platform for online prediction and I'm querying it with the python `googleclientapi`.

However the task takes about 30s to complete, so when I invoke multiple requests and before the model starts scaling up, I get that some responses are:

`[Error] <HttpError 503 when requesting https://us-central1-ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/... returned "Timed out waiting for notification", referer: https://..."`

I've searched a lot for a solution and I tried to increase the request timeout via socket:
`socket.setdefaulttimeout(300)` but noyhing changes.

Comment: Setting a socket timeout will not help as the service is returning a response. That response is the error `HTTP 503 Service Unavailable`. Add code that waits/sleeps and then tries again. Note: edit your question and show the code and the error messages.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you need GPU to make prediction?

Comment: Yes, but I was testing with only CPU in order to verify the behavior with high latency